# Failed to create VM from Azure DevOps Pipeline to Terraform

Tags: azure, terraform

When you create a VM from the Azure DevOps Pipeline to Terraform, you want to automatically perform tasks such as installing java.

The following error occurred during Terraform Apply, but I don't know how to solve it.

```
╷
│ Error: file provisioner error
│ 
│   with azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.default[0],
│   on CreateWindows10VM.tf line 133, in resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "default":
│  133:   provisioner "file" {
│ 
│ timeout - last error: unknown error Post "http://10.0.8.4:5985/wsman": dial
│ tcp 10.0.8.4:5985: connectex: A connection attempt failed because the
│ connected party did not properly respond after a period of time, or
│ established connection failed because connected host has failed to respond.
╵
##[error]Cmd.exe exited with code '1'.
```

Azure security group allowed rules for 5985 ports.

After connecting RDP to the created VM, permission for remote management appears to be blocked when performing the command below.

```
winrm quickconfig
WinRM service is already running on this machine.
WinRM is not set up to allow remote access to this machine for management.
The following changes must be made:

Enable the WinRM firewall exception.
Configure LocalAccountTokenFilterPolicy to grant administrative rights remotely to local users.

Make these changes [y/n]?
```

```
PS C:\Users\Tester> Get-NetFirewallRule -Name *WINRM* | Format-Table Name, DisplayName, Action, Direction, Enabled

Name                             DisplayName                                              Action Direction Enabled
----                             -----------                                              ------ --------- -------
WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP-NoScope        Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)                       Allow   Inbound   False
WINRM-HTTP-In-TCP                Windows Remote Management (HTTP-In)                       Allow   Inbound   False
WINRM-HTTP-Compat-In-TCP-NoScope Windows Remote Management - Compatibility Mode (HTTP-In)  Allow   Inbound   False
WINRM-HTTP-Compat-In-TCP         Windows Remote Management - Compatibility Mode (HTTP-In)  Allow   Inbound   False
```

CreateWindows.tf

```
data "azurerm_network_security_group" "default" {
  name                = "test-nsg"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface_security_group_association" "default" {
  count                      = var.subnet_count
  network_interface_id = azurerm_network_interface.default[count.index].id
  network_security_group_id = data.azurerm_network_security_group.default.id
}

# Azure portal 
resource "azurerm_public_ip" "default" {
  count               = var.subnet_count
  name                = "publicip-${random_integer.default[count.index].result}"
  location            = var.location
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  allocation_method   = "Dynamic"
}

data "local_file" "subnet_result" {
  filename = "subnet_result.json"
}
locals {
  subnet_result = jsondecode(data.local_file.subnet_result.content)
}
resource "azurerm_subnet" "default" {
  count                = var.subnet_count
  name                 = "subnet-${random_integer.default[count.index].result}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  virtual_network_name = azurerm_virtual_network.default.name
  address_prefixes     = [local.subnet_result.subnet]
}

resource "azurerm_network_interface" "default" {
  count                = var.subnet_count
  name                 = "nic-${random_integer.default[count.index].result}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location

  ip_configuration {
    name                          = "internal"
    subnet_id                     = azurerm_subnet.default[count.index].id
    private_ip_address_allocation = "Dynamic"
    public_ip_address_id           = azurerm_public_ip.default[count.index].id
  }

  tags = {
    environment = "test"
  }
}

resource "random_integer" "default" {
  count = var.subnet_count
  min   = 1000
  max   = 9999
}

resource "azurerm_virtual_network" "default" {
  name                = "vnet-default"
  resource_group_name = var.resource_group_name
  location            = var.location
  address_space       = ["10.0.0.0/16"]
}

resource "azurerm_windows_virtual_machine" "default" {
  count                = var.subnet_count
  name                 = "vm-${random_integer.default[count.index].result}"
  resource_group_name  = var.resource_group_name
  location             = var.location
  size                 = var.vm_size
  admin_username = var.admin_username
  admin_password = var.admin_password

  network_interface_ids = [azurerm_network_interface.default[count.index].id]

  os_disk {
    caching              = var.os_disk_caching
    storage_account_type = var.os_disk_storage_type
  }

  source_image_reference {
    publisher = var.publisher
    offer     = var.offer
    sku       = var.sku
    version   = var.windows_version
  }

  provisioner "file" {
    source      = "${path.module}/file/java.ps1"
    destination = "C:\\Temp\\java.ps1"

    connection {
      type     = "winrm"
      user     = "var.admin_username"
      password = "var.admin_password"
      host     = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.default[count.index].private_ip_address
    }
  }

  provisioner "remote-exec" {
    inline = [
      "powershell.exe -ExecutionPolicy Bypass C:\\Temp\\java.ps1"
    ]
  }
}

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
  skip_provider_registration = true
}
```

host     = azurerm_windows_virtual_machine.default[count.index].private_ip_address

public_ip_address setting error used private_ip_address

In this release there's a known issue where the public_ip_address and public_ip_addresses fields may not be fully populated for Dynamic Public IP's.

Please let me know if you have any similar work experience or if you have a code to refer to

Expected to create VM with terraform and java.ps1 file to run but failed

Comment: Do the pipeline agent's server has access to the network you're trying to reach (10.0.8.4)? By using the private IP it requires that a route between the provisioning agent and the actual target resource be established.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use **Private IP Address** of VM for **remote-exec/file provisioner**, than you will need a **self-hosted agent** deployed in same network (same virtual network or peered virtual networks) for executing the pipeline, **microsoft-hosted agents won't work**.

To create Self-hosted agents/Agent pools: [Self-hosted Windows agents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/agents/windows-agent?view=azure-devops)

If you are using microsoft-hosted agents your **host** must be a **Public IP Address**.

```
  provisioner "file" {
     source      = "${path.module}/file/java.ps1"
     destination = "C:\\Temp\\java.ps1"

     connection {
        type     = "winrm"
        user     = "var.admin_username"
        password = "var.admin_password"
        host     = self.public_ip_address
     }
 }
```